# How to see the result of an AJAX in Python and Selenium

Tags: javascript, django, testing, selenium

I'm testing a Django site using Selenium. I have added a function to report javascript errors via Google Analytics, how can I write a test that checks that when there is a javascript error an AJAX call is made to Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

Use your JavaScript error handler to detect error in AJAX and then it sets some global JavaScript flag variable. Then you can read the content of any JavaScript variable in Selenium. Here is an example to wait 10 seconds to see if JavaScript variable is set to true:

```
def wait_javascript_ready(browser):
    """Check app specific flag which signals all our jQuery magic is up'n'running."""
    timeout = time.time() + 10

    while time.time() < timeout:
        flag = browser.evaluate_script("window.javascriptReady == true")
        if flag:
            return
        time.sleep(0.1)

    raise AssertionError("Did not get window.javascriptReady JS flag")
```